# Generating a unique random number on the paper without involving time or other sensory information

Tags: random, random-functions

Is there any mathematical approach for calculating a unique random number completely by hand on the paper without taking help from the computer in a way that:

1- Time would not be involved

2- No sensory data would be involved

3- That number can never ever be resulted using that approach again

For example: given that I have a flock of horses, all white, equally the same size, whose ages are unknown and I want to identify them by numbers in a way that no other white horse owned by anyone else would have that number (given all horses in the world are identified by numbers). also given that it's year 200 where there is no computer or calculator.

Is there any a pure mathematical solution for this problem?

Comment: So you want a proccess that gives you a random mumber, and if someome else somewhere on earth also used that proccess to number their horse, that proccess will not give you the same number?

Comment: why do it randomly?  why not just number them $1,2,3,\cdots$?  if more than one person is doing it, just tag on a suffix identifying that person.

Comment: @Ovi: Exactly! yeah that is what I mean.

Comment: @lulu: Because someone else may also do as 1,2,3. In that case there may be two horse with the same identity!

Comment: They will have different suffixes.  As I say, start or end the string with something that uniquely identifies the person producing it.

Comment: @lulu: As I said, given all horses are identified by numbers. I'm not a math person as I am software engineer, I wanna know how to do unique random number generation on the paper without taking help form computers. Because they generate them based on sensory information.

Comment: @lulu: I cannot change the problem :D unfortunately, the problem is only an example of what I mean.

Comment: Well, are you asking a practical question or an abstract one?  If the identifying numbers are bounded in length then of course there can be no scheme which guarantees the absence of a duplicate.  On the other hand, if you choose a random $20$ digit number, then the probability of a match is comfortably negligible.

Comment: @lulu: You are trying to make this problem simple, but as I said, the main problem is Unique Random Number Generation on the paper. Suffix is (sorry to say) a not very intelligent solution because again it results in duplicates. About probability, I need 0% chance of duplicate like fingerprint

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but estimates on the probability of duplicate fingerprints range from about $10^{-11}$ to $10^{-75}$.  If you are willing to work with $100+$ digit numbers you can certainly get this level of precision by simple means.  But, I think it's clear that I don't understand what you are after, so I'll leave it here.

Comment: @lulu: Not a math guy, but this just came into my mind, do you think if I use the P number and select like 32 digits at a random point after the decimal point, I could come up with a unique random number?

Comment: No!  for the reason I keep saying.  If the length is bounded, then each possible number has a non-zero (albeit small) probability of being selected and therefore there is a non-zero probability of a duplicate.  Initially, I had assumed that you wanted a practical solution (and so would settle for a very low probability) but now I don't understand what the goal is.

Comment: "I want to identify them by numbers in a way that no other white horse owned by anyone else would have that number"  That is absolutely and completely contradictory with the numbers being random.

Comment: For your purpose randomness is not required but uniqueness is.  These are different issues.

Answer (score 1):

From the conditions that you have, the answer is no. You cannot have such an algorithm. Suppose you have one machine only that gives these numbers. The machine knows which number it generated, so it has the notion of time (might not be linear, but it is monotonic). If you have more than one machine, say one that produces odd numbers, one that produces evens, each of them will have the notion of time (same reasoning as before). In addition, there is the sensory data condition that is contradicted (I can find out which machine I have).

Comment: How about an algorithm with an input in which a very small change on that input (like 0.5 to 0.500000000001) could cause a significant impact on the output. So that a single variable could hugely impact the result?

Comment: @Plexus Haha i was just about to comment that. Those functions exist, but i don't know any myself, i hope someone more knowledgable will show up. But I think it has something to do with functions they use for encrypting data.

Comment: @Ovi: You are taking about hashing algorithms! NO!!! I already know those things, they behave differently.

Comment: Well, if sensory and time input isn't allowed what input *is*?  You have to have *something* to set the function off.  Otherwise it will always generate the exact same numbers.

It's really beginning to sound like you are asking for 13 invisible purple straight lines that spiral and can be divided into groups of 7.  And getting irritated when we suggest it might not be practical.

Comment: @fleablood: I don't get irritated at all and I also didn't. I have been thinking about how to create unique random numbers using pure mathematical functions. For example I have been considering the P number since the numbers that come after its decimal point never repeat exactly. There are many other number like P as well which in my opinion can be used for random number generation and you do not need to involve any sensory data. You can start from the decimal point and move forward to the infinity and select the range of numbers you want. However, a lulu said, there's a chance of duplicates.

Comment: But.... how do you determine which P number machine 1 will use and which P number machine 2 will use?  And how is that determination any different than sensory or time input?